# Modify Bootstrap by changing source or overwriting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am at the moment working on the frontend of a larger project using bootstrap. I am using the sass version to easily modify bootstrap and so I wondered if it is better practice to actually change the source code of bootstrap (and by that I mean more than variables) or to overwrite it with seperate code.

To illustrate what I mean:

SOURCE

```
.some-bootstrap {
    rule-a: foo;
    rule-b: bar;
}
```

CHANGE

```
.some-bootstrap {
    rule-a: newstuff;
    rule-new: dummy;
}
```

OVERWRITE:

```
//in bootstrap
.some-bootstrap {
    rule-a: foo;
    rule-b: bar;
}

//in own file
.some-bootstrap {
    rule-b: none;
    rule-new: dummy
}
```

I think this is not only a question of preference, its also a question of best practice. Is there anybody who tried both and can tell about issues with one way?

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is we should **never** change the library. If we want to do customization, override instead. Think about what happens if we want to **upgrade the library to a new version** (all your changes are lost)

If you work with bootstrap, there are many places you can do your customization: variables, overriding styles with more specific selectors,...